# Highcarts doesn't load my JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart using Highcharts. My JSON output is a regular JSON format, generated by PHP's json_encode().
Here is my JSON output:

```
[["2015-07-13 16:41:05","3"],["2015-08-15 16:41:05","1"],["2015-09-18 16:41:05","4"],["2015-10-28 16:41:05","3"],["2015-11-20 16:41:05","1"],["2015-11-28 16:41:05","5"],["2015-12-13 16:41:05","1"],["2015-12-21 16:41:05","2"],["2015-12-24 16:41:05","1"],["2015-12-25 16:41:05","2"],["2015-12-28 16:41:05","1"],["2016-01-03 16:41:05","2"],["2016-01-09 16:41:05","4"],["2016-01-14 16:41:05","6"],["2016-01-17 16:41:05","3"],["2016-01-18 16:41:05","3"],["2016-01-20 16:41:05","2"],["2016-01-21 16:41:05","2"],["2016-01-22 16:41:05","2"],["2016-01-23 16:41:05","1"],["2016-01-24 16:41:05","5"],["2016-01-25 13:41:05","1"],["2016-01-25 16:41:00","1"],["2016-01-25 16:41:05","1"],["2016-01-27 16:41:05","1"],["2016-01-28 16:41:05","1"],["2016-01-29 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-09 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-10 16:41:05","2"],["2016-02-11 16:41:05","3"],["2016-02-15 16:41:05","2"],["2016-02-18 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-21 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-23 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-24 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-25 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-26 16:41:05","1"],["2016-02-28 16:41:05","1"],["2016-03-01 16:41:05","1"],["2016-03-02 16:41:05","1"],["2016-03-05 16:41:05","1"],["2016-03-12 16:41:05","1"],["2016-03-21 16:41:05","1"],["2016-04-25 16:41:05","1"],["2016-05-05 16:41:05","2"],["2016-05-11 16:41:05","1"],["2016-05-12 16:41:05","1"],["2016-05-24 16:41:05","1"],["2016-05-25 16:41:05","1"],["2016-06-01 16:41:05","1"],["2016-06-12 16:41:05","1"],["2016-06-25 10:41:05","1"],["2016-06-25 16:41:05","1"],["2016-07-01 10:41:05","1"],["2016-07-01 16:41:05","1"],["2016-07-02 16:41:05","1"],["2016-07-25 16:21:05","1"],["2016-07-25 16:41:05","1"],["2016-08-13 16:41:05","1"],["2016-08-28 16:41:05","1"],["2016-09-20 16:41:05","3"],["2016-09-29 16:41:05","2"],["2016-10-01 14:20:18","1"],["2016-10-09 14:20:18","1"],["2016-10-10 14:20:18","1"],["2016-10-28 14:20:18","2"],["2016-10-30 14:20:18","2"],["2016-11-01 13:44:29","1"],["2016-11-06 08:26:18","2"],["2016-11-10 13:44:29","1"],["2016-11-13 13:44:29","2"],["2016-11-14 19:13:42","4"],["2016-11-15 23:27:39","3"],["2016-12-06 19:04:06","3"],["2016-12-08 10:49:28","3"],["2016-12-10 23:01:44","1"],["2016-12-14 21:27:44","1"],["2016-12-15 23:27:44","2"],["2016-12-15 23:27:53","3"],["2016-12-18 18:06:28","1"],["2016-12-21 20:06:28","3"],["2016-12-23 20:06:20","5"],["2016-12-29 20:18:18","3"],["2017-01-03 20:06:32","3"]]
```

But Highcarts doesn't load the data in the chart. The URL, output and data are all set. The request returns 200 and the data can be loaded regularly as I've checked it by AJAX.
Here is my Highchart function. Please note that I got several reports in my application. It's why I've specified the cartFilling() function:

```
function cartFilling() {
    var url = 'components/com_product/views/reports/callback.php?callback=cart-filling&date='+date_scope;
    jQuery.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        Highcharts.chart('cartFilling', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Shopping Cart Filling Actions'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Carts Filled'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Cart Filling',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to parse date string to javascript timestamp. Instead of this "2015-07-13 16:41:05", you need sth like this 1436798465000. Use new Date("2015-07-13 16:41:05").getTime() to parse your json.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works perfectly, you just need to rewrite the data array.

Instead of this:

```
["2015-07-13 16:41:05", "3"]
```

Use this:

```
[Date.UTC(2015,6,13,16,41,5), 3]
```

Please note that in the Date.UTC function 0=January,1=February, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpegbt7t/

Comment: It still doesn't work Daniel. The valid JSON format is ["Date.UTC(2015,6,13,16,41,5)", "3"]. I tried it but useless. Also I removed the quotations so it said: [Date.UTC(2015,6,13,16,41,5), 3]. This one didn't work as well. What do you think?

Comment: I have used HighCharts 5.0.7 with jQuery 1.8.2, it worked for me.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

HighChart requires number type for the second element in the array.

Comment: Added type: 'number' to yAxis but useless. I had problem with retrieving data cause of the type of data which was not JSON. Also, the date was problem. So, I couldn't see the chart loaded at all. But now I made several corrections. Though it's not working but at least, I can see an empty chart now.

Comment: Please see the fiddle I added in the answer.

After retrieving the data format it correctly, parse the numbers with praseInt() or parseFloat() and the dates as well.